# TypeORM Unidirectional Many To One relation

Tags: typeorm

I am creating the entities that make up my db schema. 
I have the entity `Photo` that is bound to the entity `Hashtag` in a many to one relation (each photo has one hashtag, and each hashtag can belong to many photos).

In order to do this, as per TypeOrm documentation, I have to do the following.
In the **Photo** entity :

```
@ManyToOne(type => HashtagEntity, hashtag => hashtag.Photos)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'HashtagId' })
Hashtag: HashtagEntity;
```

And in the **Hashtag** entity :

```
@OneToMany(type => PhotoEntity, photo => photo.Hashtag)
Photos: PhotoEntity[];
```

I have read that all entities are eagerly loaded in TypeOrm. Does this mean that each time I query a hashtag I materialize all the photos associated to it?
If this is the case, it's very bad as I only need the reference to the Hashtag from the photo and not the other way around.

How can I solve this? Should I use a `OneToOne` relation on the `Photo` entity or is there a way to make a unidirectional `ManyToOne`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeORM relations are not automatically `eager`ly loaded unless you specify otherwise in the the Entity definition.
In order to materialize relations, the name of the foreign key property  must be specified in the `relations` array of the query.

Comment: What is this supposed to mean? Can you share an example?